# Use Kafka topics to store data for many years

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking for a way of collecting metrics data from multiple devices. The data should be aggregated by multiple "group by" like functions. The aggregation functions list is not complete and new aggregations will be added later and it will be required to aggregate all data collected from first days.

Is it fine to create Kafka topic with 100 year expiration period and use it as a datastore for this purpose? So new aggregations will be able to read from topic's start while existing aggregations will continue from their's offsets?

Comment: Assuming you have the resources available, you should ideally dump to an actual filesystem like HDFS or S3 if you are dealing with a century of data. The data will likely outlive the applications that are processing it. Also, you would need to ensure Kafka is always running and have enough hard drives to store and read years worth of data.

Comment: Something to keep in mind as well is that cluster restarts (especially after unclean shutdowns) might take a very long time, as all logs would need to be checked at broker startup. Apart from that I can't think of large reasons not to do this, though I agree that dumping data to S3/HDFS/similar should be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle, yes you can use Kafka for long-term storage, exactly for the reason you outline - reprocessing of source data to derive additional aggregates/calculations.

A couple of references:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/okay-store-data-apache-kafka/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/publishing-apache-kafka-new-york-times/

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to keep the data you can just increase the retention time to a large value.

I'd still recommend having a retention policy on size to ensure you don't run out of disk space

Comment: What about having a compacted topic?