# Is Kafka a message queue and can Kafka be used as the database?

Tags: apache-kafka

Some places mentioned Kafka is the publish-subscribe messaging. Other sources mentioned  Kafka is the Message Queue. May I ask the differences between those and can Kakfa be used as the database?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you add some details around what exactly you are looking for with some example

Comment: Kafka calls itself a "Stream Processing Platform". It's a real system but no" architectural style". I would not call it a database.

Comment: Your question is not clear and looks confused when comparing 2 different things but it is valid for some points. I have edited the question to make it clear. Please feel free to change if it is not correct as your original ideas.

Comment: Worth to read this.   .....https://www.datanami.com/2019/10/01/kafka-transforming-into-event-streaming-database/

Comment: And this https://martin.kleppmann.com/2018/10/17/kafka-summit.html

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 patterns named Publish-Subscribe and Message Queue. There are some places discussed the differences. [here](https://streaml.io/resources/tutorials/concepts/messaging-and-queuing)

Kafka especially supports both of these 2 patterns. For the publish-subscribe pattern, Kafka has publisher/subscriber which supported this pattern. The publisher sends messages to one topic and the subscriber can subscribes and receives messages on that one. For the queueing pattern, Kafka has a concept named Consumer Group. Within the same consumer group, all consumers will share jobs hence balancing the workload.

Because of the flexible design from the start, Kafka is broadly used for many software patterns while designing the system.
Personally, I would not call Kafka itself a database but you can use Kafka as the storage, especially through some mechanisms such as the [log compaction](https://towardsdatascience.com/log-compacted-topics-in-apache-kafka-b1aa1e4665a7). [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925924/use-kafka-topics-to-store-data-for-many-years) [Ref2](https://www.confluent.io/blog/okay-store-data-apache-kafka/)

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is a storage at base like a database but without indexes, where every query is a full scan of your data. Kafka it store data in files that can not be modified. Ex if you use event sourcing you can save all event of your system in Kafka and reprocess all events when your system have a bug.

Imagine that Kafka can split a very huge file(10TB or more) on multiple server and provide a way to read that file in a distributed manner using partitions( more partition you have, more application can read in parallel).

Because its a storage, Kafka can also be used as a message queue or as a publish-subscribe system.